# How should I structure my Firebase Firestore Data to replicate Slack web app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, slack, react-context

Basically I am trying to build a web app similar to Slack using React and Firebase/Firestore. I can build a chat-room-like-Slack web app where user can create multiple channels to chat. However, I do not know how to replicate the `workspace` concept of Slack. Take this URL for example: `https://app.slack.com/client/T01X6XXXXXX/X01X9XXXXXX` , the number after /client/: `T01X6XXXXXX` is the unique ID of the workspace and only invited user can join. Once joined, invited user can see all the channels created before by the other user. Random user cannot join this workspace since they don't know the ID of the workspace.

So my question is: How can I build a chat rooms with this `workspace` concept with React/Firebase/Firestore? How should I structure my Firestore Db?

Currently, my Firestore Data looks like this:

`/rooms/HgUYoCYI45DCTScIMYEG/messages`

The number in between rooms (collections) and messages (collections) is the channel Id. The channel (document) consists of `channelName` and `channelId`.

I'm only a beginner and I don't know if this a dumb question or not. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every document in your chat room should have an array of members where you store user Ids , and in your front end if a user opens a certain chat room you check if their Id is in the chat room members array if not redirect , also if your using fireStore you can easily query a users chat rooms by using `collection('chatrooms').where('members','array-contains',userId)`

Comment: What if I add a "workspaces" collection on top of "rooms" ? So the Firestore Date should looks like: /workspaces/:workspaceId/rooms/:roomId/...

Comment: Would something like this work?

Comment: yeah you mean a sub collection ? its an option you can explore of course

Comment: shouldn't it be rooms that are on top of workspaces logically , a workspace can have multiple rooms not the opposite